# js - "block" or "redirect" all keyboard and mouse wheel actions

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

Is it possible to "block" or "redirect" all keyboard and mouse wheel actions using some js code? It could be something tied to the body of the page, for example.

The idea is to "prevent" the user from interacting with the page during the execution of certain js operations. During these intervals a div appears covering the entire screen and displays an animated gif in its center.

NOTE: Please, if possible, present some model or example of how this can be done.

---

UPDATE: After executing the js operation mentioned above the "block" or "redirect" is removed.

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` for events you want to default behavior

Comment: Can you provide some model or example of how this can be done? Thanks!

Comment: Why is the modal not enough? Sounds like you writing spam...

Comment: @Zach Smith Because otherwise the user will be able to use the mouse wheel and the tab key to "navigate" through the elements of the page, for example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for events at a document level.

```
[...events].forEach(e => {
  document.addEventListener(e, (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault()
    ... 
  })
})
```

But there's definitely a code smell... I doubt that intercepting all events is a good Idea. Ever.

Comment: See the update I made in the above question. I believe it answers your question. Thanks! =D

Comment: Still sounds like there are better ways. I edited answer to be more helpful

Comment: I will test the solutions presented and give you feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `preventDefault`:

```js
var events = "mousedown mouseup click dblclick mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave scroll contextmenu keydown keypress keyup";
events.split(" ").forEach(event => document.addEventListener(event, e => e.preventDefault()));
```

```html
<p>This is some example text. Please ignore it.</p>
```

Try selecting the text in the snippet above, then deselecting it.

Comment: I will test the solutions presented and give you feedback. Thank you!